# C language, increase each number of sequence by 1. how to remove 0 in the begining

Tags: c, recursion, visual-studio-2017

You receive a number. Function should create a new number by changing each number (d=1,2,3,...) of the number to d+1. If 9 is in the middle of the number will be turned into 0. You should not check if the specific number is 9 (!) .
The function should return a new number.

The problem in my code is that when I get a number that starts with 9, in the beginning it shows 0 (but it shouldn't as shown in examples below).

```
//if input 879021 - output 980132
//if input 930 - output 41
//if input 9999 - output 0
//working with visual studio 2017

void num_incr(int number);

void main(){
   int number = 0;
   printf("Enter a whole number: ");
   scanf_s("%d", &number);
   num_incr(number);
}

void num_incr(int number) {
   if (number <= 0) {
      return;
   }
   num_incr(number / 10);
   printf("%d", (number % 10 + 1) % 10);
}
```

Comment: Unless you enter give a negative number as input, no calls to `num_incr` will be called with `number < 0`. That means you actually have infinite recursion. That would have been easy to find out if you [knew how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: we should assume we get a positive whole number

Comment: Infinite recursion it is then, no matter the (positive) input.

Comment: You are missing the point. Your stop condition is never true. Also re: *"The function should return a new number"* - printing and returning are vastly different things.

Comment: it is true as i divide the number by 10 each time the function calls

Comment: @ElenaGo Yes. And what is e.g. `930 / 10`? It's `93` and `93 >= 0`. Then you continue with `93 / 10` which is `9`, and `9 >= 0`. Then you continue with `9 / 10` which is `0` and `0 >= 0` is true so you continue with `0 / 10` which is `0` and so on and on and on and on... The function *never* reaches the `printf` call, and it should not print anything at all. In fact it should lead to a *crash* (after a long while).

Comment: so it works except you print out leading 0s and you're not supposed to?

Comment: If ( number == 0 ){ return; }

Comment: but i check if my number is less then or equal to 0, not greater

Comment: @ElenaGo Please read the comment from StoyTeller. Moreover, the statement should be phrased very carefully to avoid doubts. Specifically the number should probably be non negative. Solve this: "Write a function which receives an unsigned int and returns an unsigned int in which every digit of its decimal representation is substituted by its successor (9 becomes 0)." After you wrote such a function, test it with this: `int main(void) { unsigned int x = num_incr(930); }`. **Use a debugger** to read the value of x.

Answer (score 1):

To remove 0 in beginning, first make the return function as integer and print at last.

also In current code, the recursion is not finished because positive integer will be still positive when it is divided by 0.

```
//if input 879021 - output 980132
//if input 930 - output 41
//if input 9999 - output 0
//working with visual studio 2017

int num_incr(int number);

void main(){
   int number = 0;
   printf("Enter a whole number: ");
   scanf_s("%d", &number);
   printf("%d\n", num_incr(number));
}

int num_incr(int number) {
   if (number <= 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   int up_part = num_incr(number / 10);
   return up_part * 10 + ((number % 10 + 1) % 10);
}
```

Comment: It works on my server (Linux, only changing scanf_s to scanf).. can I ask for specific inputs which is not correct?

Comment: on visual studio 2017 it requires use of scanf_s()

Comment: Oh I didn't understand the question cleary. Sorry for that.

Comment: @ElenaGo nope, Visual C is trying to force you to use MS non standard functions. The sooner you escape their clutches, the better. At the top (before any `#include`) I have the following three lines: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS \ #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE \ #define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` so I can ignore their attempts to hi-jack C.

Comment: still didn't solve the problem, but thanks for that! yet helpful!

Comment: @ElenaGo my comment wasn't a solution, but a reply to your *"on visual studio 2017 it requires use of `scanf_s()`"*. Either stop using Visual C, or **force** it to allow standard C functions like `scanf` without it complaining. If you go along with MS demands, your code will be non-standard and non-portable.

Comment: @WeatherVane `scanf_s()` echos [the 3 E's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)